# apt-get upgrade produces ERROR: The Sage installation tree has moved

Tags: upgrade, sagemath

Running `sudo apt-get upgrade` I get the following error.  I am not sure how to fix this (I usually just use apt-get to install and upgrade, not sure how to fix it when it fails).

```
primes$ sudo apt-get install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.

Setting up sagemath-upstream-binary (7.0~aimsppa1~qa201602031255151) ...
Running Sage once as root to set paths

Rewriting paths for your new installation directory
===================================================

This might take a few minutes but only has to be done once.

patching /usr/lib/sagemath/src/build/cythonized/sage/rings/real_arb.c
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/sagemath/relocate-once.py", line 85, in <module>
    p('src/build/cythonized/sage/rings/real_arb.c').substitute().save()
  File "/usr/lib/sagemath/relocate-once.py", line 70, in __call__
    return FilePatch(self, filename)
  File "/usr/lib/sagemath/relocate-once.py", line 21, in __init__
    self.st = os.stat(filename)
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/lib/sagemath/src/build/cythonized/sage/rings/real_arb.c'
┌────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ SageMath Version 7.0, Release Date: 2016-01-19                     │
│ Type "notebook()" for the browser-based notebook interface.        │
│ Type "help()" for help.                                            │
└────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘

ERROR:  The Sage installation tree has moved

from    /mnt/highperf/buildbot/slave/binary_pkg/build/source/SageMath/jc4b6yulaujayb9sr94ia88eourzeqip0oidma
  to /usr/lib/sagemath

This is not supported, and Sage will not work. To install Sage from a
binary package:

1. Open the .tar.bz2 archive (or .dmg on OSX)

2. Move the SageMath folder/app to where you want it to be. You can also rename the directory now.

3. Start sage for the first time. This will then automatically patch paths in binaries.

After starting Sage for the first time you cannot change the
installation any more. To install Sage elsewhere, start over from the
binary package. Or recompile Sage from scratch in the new location
("make distclean && make")

dpkg: error processing package sagemath-upstream-binary (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

It does list some steps I could try to follow but not sure which .tar.bz2 archive nor where I want it to be so that upgrade will work in the future.

```
Linux 3.13.0-76-generic #120-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jan 18 15:59:10 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Just FYI, I've started running into the same thing since updating `sagemath-upstream-binary` on Debian Jessie last week.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[On the mailinglist](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.mathematics.sage.devel/84736), one of the Sage developers mentioned that this is a known issue with 7.0 and should be fixed soon. That was posted on 2016-02-04.

It appears that it has since been fixed with the `7.0~aimsppa1~qa201602060140061` release, (i.e. on 2016-02-06). I just ran `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade` and this problem was indeed fixed.

Comment: My favorite type of response "just wait, someone is fixing it for you."  All is well on my machine now too.